# generic class inherits generic interface but generates and error at compile

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IModel<T>
{
    List<T> responseIds { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a generic class which implements the interface :

```
class SFDCResponse<T> : SFDCBaseResponse, IModel<T>
{
    public List<T> responseIds;
}
```

Finally, I define a class like so:

```
class SFDCAccounts : SFDCResponse<MyClass> { }
```

However, at compile time I get the following error:

```
SFDCResponse<T> does not implement interface member IModel<T>.responseIds
```

Is it not possible to have a generic class inherit a generic interface and have teh compiler verify the class a compile time?

Comment: You are aware that there are code actions, that will automatically generate your interface so you won't encounter these issues

Comment: Your problems would be much clearer if you stick to the casing convention recommended for C#. Properties are PascalCase and fields are camelCase [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx). You can see that the interface declares a property which your class lacks.

Answer (score 0):

responseIds is a Property in the interface and a Field in the implementing class.  Make it a Property and that should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. That was it and I realized when I pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just looking at my own post I realized that my SFDCResponse class implemented the responseIds as a field and not as a property. I just corrected to:

```
class SFDCResponse<T> : SFDCBaseResponse, IModel<T>
{
    public List<T> responseIds { get; set; }
}
```

And the app compiled. Sometimes just going through this process gets you your own answer.

Comment: Fixed by the rubber duck.